# Matching multiple occurrences of consecutive characters from a set

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match 3 or more consecutive occurrences of one/more special characters from  a set in a string.

```
my js:
var exp = new RegExp("^[\^\$\*%#`!]{3}+$"); 
return !exp.test(myString);
```

Not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```
this i$ a te$t: false
th!$ a te$t: false

th!s is a ^%* test: true 
as it has 3 consecutive characters from my set '^%*'

this is a ^%^&%&%& test: true
as it has 3 or more consecutive characters from my set
```

**EDIT:**

I corrected the regex. **This in JavaScript**

```
var exp = new RegExp("[\^$%#`]{3}"); return exp.test(myString);
```

**Why it is saying this is a match?
%^ $^ $^ $^ &^ &^ & %**

This input has 2 characters at most and has space in between.

Comment: your regex is invalid, you can't have the `+` after the `{3}` that's like saying "I want it exactly 3 times, but also 1 or more times is acceptable."

Comment: in your update, that is matching because you have a space in the character set.... check my answer below... i've tested it and it seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want

```
/[\^$*%#`!]{3,}/
== new RegExp("[\\^$*%#`!]{3,}")
```

Your string should have a occurence of these characters, not consist out of them. Also, `.{3}+` seems odd to me.

---

EDIT (to answer your extended question):

Also, if you want to escape the ^ with a backslash, you will have to escape the backslash itself in the string for your RegExp constructor. Your `new RegExp("[\^$%#']{3}")` equals `/[^$%#']{3}]/`, which matches the sequence `"^ &"`.

Comment: I think you need to escape the `^` in the character set

Comment: possible, but in his example he didn't either.

Answer (score 3):

```
new RegExp("[\^\$\*%#`!]{3}");
```

The leading `^` indicated that the pattern must start at the beginning of the string. The trailing `$` indicated that the pattern must end at the end of the string. The combination of these would indicate that the only valid match is a string consisting only of your special characters.

Finally, the `+` isn't necessary, at soon as you find the first 3 consecutive special characters, you're done; that it can match 5 is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for only 3 characters between the ^ and $ of the string. You'll want to pad on either end with .*? (or just leave out the ^ and $).

http://regexpal.com/ is always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Regex:

```
/[\^$*%#`!]{3,}/
```

Javascript tests:

```
var result = new RegExp(/[\^$*%#`!]{3,}/).test("%^ $^ $^ $^ &^ &^ & %"); 
// result now "false"
new RegExp(/[\^$*%#`!]{3,}/).test("th!s is a ^%* test"); 
// result is now "true"
```

I've removed the invalid `+` and some unnecessary escape chars. Oh, and as suggested by the other users, the Anchors `^$` are not needed .

You could however wrap the regex in `\b` tags if you wanted to limit the matches to word boundaries (so that it doesn't match in the middle of a set of characters - only if the set is on its own)